# Synchronising in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have multiple functions that transition elements, I tried to add pause and resume functionality to give the user a bit more control on the transitions.

Duration is set to 0 for pausing the elements. For resume, I have basically stored all called transition functions in an array along with pointers for each entry to keep track of the position of the dataset used for a particular transition. This works fine to an extent, [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NqJtn/) gives an example of some of the transitions I'm working with, without any interference from the user (ie no pausing and resuming) the rects and the text transition at the same time. However, once paused and resumed the two sets of rects still transition in sync but the text transitions slightly earlier than the rects, which becomes more problematic if pause and resume are used a couple more times.

Any clue as to why this could be happening when the delays are set the same?

I'm using `.each("end", ...)` to mark the transition as completed so that it won't be executed again.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you give an example where the problem occurs? Also, have you seen [this article](http://xaedes.de/dev/transitions/)?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Thanks for the link. In that article, the author is transitioning a single element with a duration. Am I right in thinking that the transition is resumed by changing the duration time based on the attribute T? If so, I'm not sure how I could adapt this method with my transitions as in the ones shows in the fiddle. 

Actually I'm think I'm a bit confused with using duration with delays. 

Perhaps, is there some way I could keep track of the total duration of the set of transitions for the red rects for example? I'm not sure if I missed the point of the article.

Comment: Without seeing the code that you're using to pause and resume I can't really help you.